# How to check if xml tag has attributes using SAX Parser in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I would like to ask you a problem regarding to xml file. I want to check if xml tag has attributes or not by using SAX Parser in Java.

Any answers? Please help me...

Comment: You get attributes as a parameter in the startElement method of your sax handler

Comment: I don't really know how it was. I use this statement to check: if(attributes.getLength()){....};. By the way, I would like to ask whether I can get only the tags' name that have attribute. Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly is the problem? Can you edit the question to show the relevant bits of your current code?

Comment: @sakura No, it is not possible in sax parser to have just the tag names with attributes. You will get all the tags in the startElement of your handler. You will need to put the filter logic yourself to ignore the tags where "attributes" is empty. If you have a small working code, post it. I will try to help

Answer (score 2):

The `startElement` method of SaxParser handler has an argument which keeps the list of attributes associated with it. You could rely on that. For example this program prints out all tags with attributes and the attribute names associated with it.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class FindTagWithAttributes {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {
                    if(attributes != null && attributes.getLength() > 0){
                        System.out.print(qName + " tag has attributes - ");
                        for(int i=0; i<attributes.getLength(); i++){
                            System.out.println(attributes.getLocalName(i));
                        }
                    }
                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName) throws SAXException {

                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {

                }

            };

            saxParser.parse("data.xml", handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```